# What can be a correct approach for SPOJ COURIER

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve [COURIER](http://www.spoj.com/problems/COURIER/) problem on spoj. I am able to understand that I have to solve TSP for this with dynamic programming approach but I am unable to exactly understand that whether my approach for handling multiple parcel between same pair of cities is correct or not. My pseudocode will be somewhat as following:

```
1) Use floyd warshall to find all pair shortest path in O(n^3). Some pair of cities are connected by more than one roads, I can just keep the shortest one for my undirected graph.
2) Add the shortest cost for each request start to end.
3) Create a new directed graph for each of 12 requests and homecity. The node of this new graph will be a merge of each request's source and destination. The edge weight between a->b can be calculated by shortest path between 'a' request's destination to 'b' request's source.I am thinking of duplicating the pairs if I have multiple request between them.
4) Use a TSP DP to solve this new undirected 13 city TSP problem. O(n^2 2^n) would come around 1384448. Not sure whether this will time out for multiple test cases.
```

Can you please give your inputs as am I complicating the problem with my approach of creating this new directed graph? I am not using the information that there are only 5 such different requests. I know I can coed this up and know but I want to get some suggestions on solution first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice problem.

After doing point 1), you can ignore all cities that are not source or address of delivery.

Therefore you have 10 cities where the traveler currently is and 2^12 possible combinations of tasks that are still to complete.

You can just do DP with two arguments: current city and deliveries to complete, that you can store with bit mask.

EDIT:

As mentioned you have two arguments: p which tracks current position and mask which tracks which visits you have already done.

Mask works as bit mask: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29

You start with mask 0, which in binary is 000000000000. When you do for example 5th requested travel you change mask to: 000000010000 etc.

You start by calling f(p=0, mask=0).

When you are solving f(p, mask) you have two options. You can move to any other city p2. You can make travel p -> p2 if this is one of travels you haven't done. Out of all these options you have to choose the best one.

This problem is quite tricky and I would suggest first solving easier problems using bit-masks to begin with. You can find some here: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=778

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I am still unable to get as how you are making TSP to visit cities multiple time for multiple deliveries? Could you please add a small pseuodcode or just a little more description. It would be great help.

Comment: No need to thank me :) just upvote and accept if you like my answer :) will make a short edit on how to approach it and leave rest to you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need the answer now or not, but here is what I did :

Initially your approach is correct, you have to apply floyd-warshall 
to get shortest distance b/w all the pairs. Now it is a classic dp+bitmask
problem. There are only 12 operations, you have to arrange these 12 operations
such that you get the minimum.

This can be done by using bitmask : 000000000000
You have these 12 states => if you pick one, you can't pick it again. And since
(2^12=4096) it will not be difficult to store such a number.

My dp states were very straight forward : 'mask number' and 'parent'
PARENT-> the last operation you have done

dp[mask][par]
Hope this will help